# Text doesn't get printed on editText after Voice Recognition in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, voice-recognition

On running, the Voice Recognition intent starts, but it does not print anything on to the `EditText`

Below is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class dialog1cl extends AppCompatActivity {
 public EditText ed;
    private static final int av= 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
        ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ImageButton im=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){

                promptspeech();
            }
        });

    }
   public void promptspeech()
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say Something!");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(i,av );
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException a)
        {
            Toast.makeText(dialog1cl.this,"Sorry! Your device doesnt support speech Language",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_code , int result_code, Intent i){



             if(request_code ==av && result_code==RESULT_OK)
             {
                List<String> result=i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
ed.setText(result.get(0));
            }
        super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:weightSum="1"

    android:id="@+id/lin1">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#FFFFBB32"
        android:contentDescription="PARAMETERS" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor = "@color/blue1"
        android:text="Task Name?"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Enter your Task"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_voice"
            android:layout_column="22" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor = "@color/blue1"
            android:text="DeadLine?"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_column="0" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_calendar"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"

            android:layout_column="22" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor = "@color/blue1"
            android:text="Time?"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_column="0" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_time"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"

            android:layout_column="22" />
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey people i apologize for such a mistake..but realised that the code was right but i made my background white in the xml file for the table layout,thus wasn't able to realise that it had been printing on the edit text....Ofcourse a rare mistake...Hope it helps someone out there..
The above code works fine for voice recognition...exclude the below part from the xml:

```
background:"@colors/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

change you on activity results with this, you have to programatically set text to your edit text

```
public void onActivityResult(int request_code , int result_code, Intent i){
         if(request_code ==av && result_code==RESULT_OK)
         {
            List<String> result=i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                ed.setText(result.get(0));
        }
    super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, i);

}
```

Comment: every thing looks fine in code, may be your speech is not recognized, try connecting your device to internet and see also add internet permission in manifest

Comment: remove the line `i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());`  and see, also print your result list and see if you are getting any strings

Answer (score 1):

Using this official tutorial I got it working for an actionbar. Take extra care while creating the searchable and meta-data.
https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

If you want the results of the text within the same activity, point the `Search Intent Filter` to your current activity and make that activity `singleInstance` or `singleTop`.

Comment: Thank You...will look into it!

Comment: thats another way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the result that you get from the activity and set the EditText's text to equal it.

```
List<String> result=i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
String text = getTextFromResult(result);
ed.setText(text);
```

Comment: there is no getTextFromResult function.

Comment: You would have to write that yourself. You need to convert the List<String> into the String you want to put into the EditText

Comment: How do i convert bro

Comment: Have you looked at this walkthrough? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html